# how to show markers list in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

**I tried this code ,but it shows me current position of the user**

---

```
public class DeveloperAdress extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {

private static final String var= Config.PORT_CONX;
private static final String TAG = DeveloperAdress.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String url =var+ "listeAddress";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
List<Address> adresss;
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

public DeveloperAdress() {

}


public static DeveloperAdress newInstance() {
    DeveloperAdress fragment = new DeveloperAdress();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adresss=getAllAdresss();




}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.developer_adress, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    for(Address address:addresss) {
      //  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude())));

        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        Marker markert = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
    return  view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);




    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext()).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }


}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Permission was granted.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }


    }
}
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}



public List<Address> getAllAddresss(){

    final List<Address> addresss = new ArrayList<Address>();

    JsonArrayRequest prodReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Address address = new Address();
                            address.setId(obj.getInt("id"));
                                         address.setLongitude(obj.getDouble("longitude"));
                            address.setLatitude(obj.getDouble("latitude"));

                            addresss.add(address);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }



                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "connexion impossible !!");
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(prodReq);

    return addresss;

}
private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }

}




@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}
}
```

Comment: what do u exaclty want? Please give more details of the problem.

Comment: Thank's  guys, I found the solution: just retrieve the list of addresses in the previous fragment and pass the list in the constructor of this fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(28.7750, 77.4183))
            .title("Marker in India")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
            .snippet("kochi").draggable(true));
```

---

Your `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` is not being called.
You need to call `getMapAsync` on the map fragment to set the `OnMapReadyCallback`

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback))

> **public void getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback callback)**
>
> Sets a callback object which will be triggered when the GoogleMap
>   instance is ready to be used.

Add this code at the end of your `onCreate` function:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Use the **Marker** Class

An icon placed at a particular point on the map's surface. A marker icon is drawn oriented against the device's screen rather than the map's surface; i.e., it will not necessarily change orientation due to map rotations, tilting, or zooming.

A marker has the following properties:

**Anchor**

The point on the image that will be placed at the LatLng position of the marker. This defaults to 50% from the left of the image and at the bottom of the image.

**Position**

The LatLng value for the marker's position on the map. You can change this value at any time if you want to move the marker.

**Title**

A text string that's displayed in an info window when the user taps the marker. You can change this value at any time.

**Snippet**

Additional text that's displayed below the title. You can change this value at any time.

**Icon**

A bitmap that's displayed for the marker. If the icon is left unset, a default icon is displayed. You can specify an alternative coloring of the default icon using defaultMarker(float). You can't change the icon once you've created the marker.

**Drag Status**

If you want to allow the user to drag the marker, set this property to true. You can change this value at any time. The default is true.

**Visibility**

By default, the marker is visible. To make the marker invisible, set this property to false. You can change this value at any time.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/anandvardhan1991/GoogleMaps-Web-API-Demo

Check this Demo for Google Web Places API.